# directions API returns INVALID_REQUEST for some URLs (and not for others)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting INVALID_REQUEST for certain requests while its working for others. For example, the following returns INVALID_REQUEST

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=EC3N4AB&destination=EC4M8AD&sensor=false&mode=transit

I have also tried several other variations like the one below:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=EC3N4AB,UK&destination=EC4M8AD,UK&sensor=false&mode=transit

This same piece of code is working for some postcodes in the UK but returning INVALID_REQUEST for others. If you search for the postcodes in google maps web interface (EC3N4AB and EC4M8AD), the web interface can easily provide directions.

Wondering what is wrong with my URL? Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

Google made `departure_time` or `arrival_time` mandatory on API requests. This URL works:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=EC3N4AB&destination=EC4M8AD&sensor=false&mode=transit&departure_time=1343376768
```

Thank everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use region parametre:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=EC3N4AB&destination=EC4M8AD&sensor=false&mode=transit&region=uk
```

Another reason may be that does not support transit (try with driving, work good ;-) )

Regards

cadetill

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. As you probably know, the region parameter doesnt work. Also, the weird things is that it works with walking and driving, just not with transit. I guess thats just coz its a new API?

Comment: Also, the transit directions between those two points work if i do it within the web interface on my website.